# How to test oEmbed discovery

Tags: oembed

I know that you can use [embed.ly](http://embed.ly) to test your oEmbed provider service, but do you know any other services where you can test [oEmbed discovery](http://oembed.com/#section4)?

I want to make sure that oEmbed-enabled consumers can correctly tap into my oEmbed provider, but I couldn't find a way to do so.

Any help or advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

iframely has a great debugger for the oembed discovery mechanism: http://debug.iframely.com/

Answer (score 2):

you could try [drupal oEmbed client/provider](https://github.com/voxpelli/drupal-oembed). Use the client to test it.

EDIT: if the above link doesn't work, try [this one](https://github.com/voxpelli/drupal-oembed) instead.

Comment: There is also a Wordpress client, and I can always write my own, but I'm interested to know if there is a known service that will help me test oEmbed discovery specifically.

Comment: For future reference: The Drupal module's home is here: https://drupal.org/project/oembed And as far as I remember it doesn't support oEmbed discovery.